# Ошибка при обновлении базы данных с условием

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Пытаюсь обновить значение одного столбца с условием в другом. Вот код:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toogle:

                Intent position = getIntent();
                int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppFavorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor value_add = settings.edit();
                sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db = sqlHelper.open();
                String strFilter = "_id=" + positionValue;

                if(birthSort){
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_off);
                    birthSort=false;
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(COLUMN_CHECK, 0);
                    db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, cv, strFilter, null);
                    value_add.putFloat(String.valueOf(positionValue), 0);
                    value_add.commit();
                }
                else{
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_on);
                    birthSort=true;
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(COLUMN_CHECK, 1);
                    db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, cv, strFilter, null);
                    value_add.putFloat(String.valueOf(positionValue), 1);
                    value_add.commit();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Вылетает с ошибкой
[image: на телефоне]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHECK` это служебное слово. Возьмите его в одинарные или двойные кавычки. А лучше не называйте так поля в таблицах.

Comment: Поменял Check на Checkbox и все заработало. Только база не сразу монтируется почему то